# How to configure Unity icons for programs not Apt-installed?

Tags: icons, unity-dash, application-switcher

I've got a couple programs that I compile myself to use newer/different versions than are in the repos, and I've managed to get the dash and other parts of the desktop to recognize them by modifying my `$PATH` in `~/.profile`, but it's obviously not picking up the icons, too.

I've tried adding .desktop files to `~/.local/share/applications`, but they're still not being used. I guess I probably want to add my libdir (`~/.opt`) to Unity's overall environment, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you make your local dir `~/.local` (ie, for my use case, run `configure --prefix=$HOME/.local` instead of `configure --prefix=$HOME/.opt`) Unity will pick up things correctly.

Additionally, it looks like if you do that .desktop files might not be necessary to get the application-switcher to recognize icons, but are still necessary to get the unity dash to recognize things as launchable applications.